# Testing Gmail Schemas Fails

Tags: email, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm trying to test [Gmail Schemas](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/) where the sender and the recipient are the same(mine) account following the [Self Testing Notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/testing-your-schema)

> You can easily test if your markup is working correctly end-to-end by
>   sending emails with schemas to your Gmail account. All emails where
>   the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the
>   registration requirements and can be used for self-testing.

but without the expected result, the "Action" button is not displayed.

I have tried using both the JSON-LD and Microdata without results.

Here the "Show original" of the email from my Gmail Account:

```
Return-Path: <fake-account-email-x@gmail.com>
Received: *****
Message-ID: <fake-email-id@gmail.com>
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 09:41:53 +0100
From: Cristian <fake-account-email-x@gmail.com>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130330 Thunderbird/17.0.5
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: fake-account-email-x@gmail.com
Subject: test
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------090703050903040805020509"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------090703050903040805020509
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


  Ciao ${FIRSTNAME}$

  * punto 1
  * punto 2
  * punto 3


--------------090703050903040805020509
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Approval request for John's
        $10.13 expense for office supplies">
      <div itemprop="action" itemscope=""
        itemtype="http://schema.org/ConfirmAction">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Approve Registration">
        <div itemprop="handler" itemscope=""
          itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
          <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Ciao ${FIRSTNAME}$</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>punto 1</li>
      <li>punto 2</li>
      <li>punto 3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>

--------------090703050903040805020509--
```

And here how it appears from the list:

[image]

And inside the message:

[image]

I have also validated my code via the [Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/)

Where is the error in my test? I can't figure out :(

## UPDATE 20131113

Sending the email via [Test Gmail Schemas](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/), as suggested Devnook, all works fine, but using my Thunderbird client(using my account via SMTP) nope.

Here the source from the test via "Test Gmail Schema"

```
Delivered-To: fake-account-email-x@gmail.com
Received: by 10.224.58.135 with SMTP id g7csp190326qah;
        Tue, 12 Nov 2013 22:48:43 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: *********
X-Original-Authentication-Results: ********
Return-Path: <3yyCDUg0JErIYeSad-SUlagfkYeSad.UgeUjaklaSf.hgjlS.UjpYeSad.Uge@2UIX4H7XYGSZ66WEERLQ.apphosting.bounces.google.com>
Received-SPF: pass ********
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
       spf=pass ********
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.224.24.65])
        by 10.224.24.65 with SMTP id u1mr35599473qab.6.1384325323511 (num_hops = 1);
        Tue, 12 Nov 2013 22:48:43 -0800 (PST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.224.24.65 with SMTP id u1mr25556165qab.6.1384325323474; Tue,
 12 Nov 2013 22:48:43 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id: s~gmail-actions
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id-Alias: gmail-actions
Message-ID: <fake-email-id@google.com>
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2013 06:48:43 +0000
Subject: Testing Gmail Actions 2013-11-13 06:48
From: fake-account-email-x@gmail.com
To: fake-account-email-x@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c2c63a28cf0504eb095b6e

--001a11c2c63a28cf0504eb095b6e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes

Ciao ${FIRSTNAME}$


punto 1
punto 2
punto 3

--001a11c2c63a28cf0504eb095b6e
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Approval request for John's
        $10.13 expense for office supplies">
      <div itemprop="action" itemscope=""
        itemtype="http://schema.org/ConfirmAction">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Approve Registration">
        <div itemprop="handler" itemscope=""
          itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
          <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Ciao ${FIRSTNAME}$</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>punto 1</li>
      <li>punto 2</li>
      <li>punto 3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
--001a11c2c63a28cf0504eb095b6e--
```

The "big" difference are that the headers of this email contains the DKIM-Signature and SPF but in theory `emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the registration requirements`

Here how it appear the "correct" email

[image]

Comment: Can you please post json-ld as well?

Answer (score 4):

I tested your email (sent it to myself using http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/) and I got the action appearing in my inbox. So your markup is fine... Are you sure you are not forwarding your email to another account?

Maybe try if other sample emails from gmail-actions.appspot.com work. If not, maybe you have some lab enabled in your inbox or a theme that is blocking the button to appear?

Also, this works only on a desktop afaik.

Comment: Hi Devnook, using the http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ all works fine but using mozilla thunderbird nope, the email are not forwarded, I send the email from thunderbird via SMPT using my account. Both email contains the Content-Type: multipart/alternative and also Content-Type: text/plain and Content-Type: text/html

Comment: I think all of the emails need to be signed with DKIM. My guess is that if the sender and recipient are the same, the DKIM signature domain does not need to match (in this sense is ignored) but the signature (any) still needs to be present.

Comment: All emails, including test ones, need to be signed with DKIM/SPF to prevent spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

When I attempt to DKIM sign the message myself, checkmyauth@auth.returnpath.net returns:

```
WARNING: The From domain 'gmail.com' does NOT match the DKIM domain
```

and gmail omits the headers (and my email remains unsigned).

Yahoo says DKIM passed by the way.

This sucks, no way to programatically test gmail actions if self signed emails to self are considered spam.

Mirza