# Email markups don't work as expected in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

My email markup passes the Email Markup Tester, I tried both JSON-LD and Microdata, but no matter what - I just don't see any effect of the markup in Gmail (iOS) client.

Even the basic example from Google's own documentation doesn't work:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started

I'm sending from my own Google account to myself, SPF is functioning.

Anybody ever got this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after trying many different methods I came to the conclusion that the official guidelines don't work (adding SPF and DKIM and sending to yourself), but luckily there is one way to test the markups before applying to Google - using the Apps Script:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial

There is an example of a little script that sends an email on behalf of you. If you put your markup in the message body - you can preview schema.org layouts in action.

Comment: Was excited to find this post, tried it, didn't work.  Raised a ticket on github - https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/issues/324

Answer (score 1):

what online resources say as here https://moz.com/blog/markup-for-emails under 'Register for email markup with Google' it's not enough to produce correct markup email and just start sending. They say we have to apply for a thorough sender review and approval procedure which you even only can start and apply if you reach to send at least hundred emails to google reciepients dayly during few weeks. It's not quite clear if you've got through such procedure yet? If not and it's still active requirement from Google then it is most likley reason your action markups wont show up. I didn't quite get if you can see markup in gmail on desktop? Regards!

Comment: Yea I know about the registration procedure, but the documentation says that anybody can test it beforehand by sending a marked up email to himself (using gmail). And after you are happy with the output - then you can register with Google. So I'm stuck at this first stage - I want to see a test email in my mailbox

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the suggestions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925000/testing-gmail-schemas-fails). Try testing the schema using `http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/`. Also make sure that you are not forwarding your email to another account.

Here are some threads which might also help:

- [Gmail Email Markup not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216823/gmail-email-markup-not-working?rq=1)

  > If you use Google SMTP relay, you have to use an SPF record looking like this:
  >
  > `600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all"`
  >
  > Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en
- [Email markup not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236320/email-markup-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question - the SPF record is set up and functioning properly. The date time format is correct too (plus even their own example doesn't work)